# Conditionally pass renderfragments to components

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor

I'm trying to conditionally pass renderfragments to a component using @if blocks but I get the build error

```
Unrecognized child content inside component 'XXX'.
```

If I have a parent component **AwesomeComponent** like this:

```
@code
{
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ItemTemplate {get; set;}
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment AnotherItemTemplate {get; set;}
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment YetAnotherItemTemplate {get; set;}
}
```

And then conditionally want to render a renderfragment like this:

```
<AwesomeComponent>

<ItemTemplate>
    // some code here
</ItemTemplate>

<AnotherItemTemplate>
    // blabla
</AnotherItemTemplate>

// This one i want to pass conditionally, the intuitive way is like this
@if (condition)
{
    <YetAnotherItemTemplate>
        // wooho
    </YetAnotherItemTemplate>
}
```

I get the `Unrecognized child content inside component` error.

I have seen solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65521318/blazor-conditionally-display-renderfragment-component). However I am also having these issues with third party components and therefore I cannot control the visibility like suggested there. Furhtermore I do not believe it's an elegant solution.

Have anyone in similar situation found a way of dealing with conditional renderfragments as described? I find it a very big limitation in Blazor.

Comment: "I find it a very big limitation in Blazor." The issue is not with Blazor

Answer (score 2):

The razor syntax let's you mix and match html and code to handle all sorts of conditional rendering, and Shaun's answer is a great example of how easy that is to do.

But, the issue, as far as I can see, is the conditional passing of child content to a component that you don't have control over. And Blazor doesn't seem to allow you to do that in razor syntax.

Assuming the component is simple (or you can break into methods), one option is two render verions, one with, one without:

```
@if (condition)
{
    <AwesomeComponent>
        <ItemTemplate>
            // some code here
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AnotherItemTemplate>
            // blabla
        </AnotherItemTemplate>
    </AwesomeComponent>
}
else
{
    <AwesomeComponent>
        <ItemTemplate>
            // some code here
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AnotherItemTemplate>
            // blabla
        </AnotherItemTemplate>
        <YetAnotherItemTemplate>
            // wooho
        </YetAnotherItemTemplate>
    </AwesomeComponent>
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this with the builder. Once you've got a number of conditionaly items to include, you'd have to resort to doing it manually.

```
@((RenderTreeBuilder b) =>
{
    b.OpenComponent<AwesomeComponent>(1);
    b.AddAddtribute(2, nameof(AwesomeComponent.ItemTemplate), itemContent);
    b.AddAddtribute(3, nameof(AwesomeComponent.AnotherItemTemplate), anotherItemContent);
    if (condition)
    {
        b.AddAddtribute(4, nameof(AwesomeComponent.YetAnotherItemTemplate), yetAnotherItemContent);
    }
    b.CloseComponent();
})
```

Where itemContent etc. are the RenderFragments as markup or methods that return RenderFragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way.  Your conditional code needs to be in the component.  You then pass the condition selector into the component as a `Parameter`.  See the code below.

##### AwesomeComponent

```
<h3>AwesomeComponent</h3>

@switch (FragmentToRender)
{
    case 1:
    @this.ItemTemplate
    break;
    case 2:
    @this.AnotherItemTemplate
    break;
    case 3:
    @this.YetAnotherItemTemplate
    break;
    default:
    <span>No Component Selected</span>
    break;
}
@code
{
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ItemTemplate {get; set;}
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? AnotherItemTemplate {get; set;}
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? YetAnotherItemTemplate {get; set;}
    [Parameter] public int FragmentToRender {get; set;}
}
```

##### Demo Page

```
@page "/"
<h3>Awesome</h3>
<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => this.ChangeComponent(1)">Display First Fragement</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="() => this.ChangeComponent(2)">Display Second Fragment</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="() => this.ChangeComponent(3)">Display Third Fragment</button>
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    <AwesomeComponent FragmentToRender=this.componentToDisplay>
        <ItemTemplate>
            One
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AnotherItemTemplate>
            Two
        </AnotherItemTemplate>
        <YetAnotherItemTemplate>
            Three
        </YetAnotherItemTemplate>
    </AwesomeComponent>
</div>

@code {
    private int componentToDisplay;

    private void ChangeComponent(int value)
    => this.componentToDisplay = value;

}
```

Comment: As mentioned one of the issues is also within third-party components and I have no control over them and therefore cannot make the conditional statements as you suggest.

Comment: [Polite]  Third party components are designed to do what they do.  You can't conditionally render parts of them unless the owners provide the necessary protected/public methods and properties for you do do so.

Comment: When content is missing, the 3rd party component can detect the null and leave it out. But if you wrap that component up into a bigger component, and that content is passed through from outside as a RenderFragment, you can't detect the null and omit passing an 'empty' section (which is not null). eg. If that was a tooltip, or error box, or similar, you'd be asking the component to give you a blank box.